# Turn on GPS by code in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-gps

I'm creating an application that use Location services, and want to give the possibility to the user to get to Location services in his android device by a simple click in the application. How must i proceed ?

Comment: I did a simple Googling with the title of your question and found `Input.location.Start();`. It's always a good idea to search what you are looking for before asking.

Comment: Sorry about my ambigius question, 
What am trying to ask is  :    how navigate the user to settings menu where to enable location services. (Initialy they are disabled)

THE GPS is not enabled by the user so the application navigate him to the setting menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 4.4 an earlier version there was a bug which let people enable GPS programmatically. So for Android 5 and later there is no way to do that.
In Unity accessing such features can only be done using Java Plug-in. 
Here is the Java code which will show a pop-up that ask the user to choose if they want let you use the GPS or not.

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

I don't know if you know how to write Java Plug-in for Unity so here is the [link](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html?m=1) where you can find a comprehensive guide.
Go to this link [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) you'll find how to convert your project to library after build your file will be here "build/output/aar/..."

Comment: I'm trying to export the .jar file but it doesn't work. In Android studio, it says that BUILD SUCCESSFUL but when i don't find the AndroidPlugin.jar in the project folder. Well another problem came by.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me perfectly !